# How should we imbed massive spin-3 in a Lorentz covariant tensor? (degree of freedom-wise)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, representation-theory, higher-spin

I'm not asking for Weinberg's systematic approach. Rather, I'm more concerned with how to get the correct degrees of freedom(*dof*) slickly for the moment.

I believe it should be imbedded in the rank 3 complete symmetric tensor $Z_{\mu\nu \alpha}$

In order to apply the ghost field method later when constructing the correct Lagrangian, I split out the transverse part of $Z_{\mu\nu \alpha}$:

$$Z_{\mu \nu \alpha}=Z_{\mu \nu \alpha}^{T}+\partial _{\mu}X_{\nu \alpha}+\partial_{\nu} X_{\alpha \mu}+\partial_{\alpha} X_{\nu \mu}$$

where$\partial^{\mu}Z_{\mu \nu \alpha}^{T}=0$

The spin-3 representation should lie in the transverse part. However, the counting of *dof* is wrong. There are 20 independent *dof* in $Z_{\mu \nu \alpha}$ and the transverse condition removes 10, leaving 10 *dof* for $Z_{\mu \nu \alpha}$.

For spin-3 we must have 7 *dof*. However, it seems there is no Lorentz covariant way to remove 3 *dof* from $Z_{\mu \nu \alpha}$. For reference, in the case of massive spin-2, the corresponding $h_{\nu\mu}^{T}$ has 6 *dof*, which we can easily remove 1 to obtain the correct 5 *dof* by imposing $h_{\ \ \mu}^{T\ \ \mu}=0$.

For massive spin-3, if we impose $Z_{\ \ \ \alpha}^{T\ \ \alpha \beta}=0$, it seems to remove 4 *dof*.

What am I doing wrong here?